# Derivative transform on Vega-Lite

Tags: transform, vega, vega-lite

I have a dataset that I need to plot the derivative function of it. Is there a way to perform the derivative of a series in Vega-Lite? Maybe a transform function or maybe with the calculate function? Is there a way to do it manually, `X(t) - X(t-1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct the operation you have in mind using a [window transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/window.html) to determine the adjacent value, followed by a [calculate transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/calculate.html) to compute the difference between the values.

Here is an example ([vega editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4yghSA3WAbArgKYDOKYA2uBhMJAB5kAMANFAJ5MC+zV1tDqAIytIHVIwB0ADm68M-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)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": 0, "y": 0},
      {"x": 1, "y": 0.8},
      {"x": 2, "y": 0.9},
      {"x": 3, "y": 0.1},
      {"x": 4, "y": -0.8},
      {"x": 5, "y": -1},
      {"x": 6, "y": -0.3},
      {"x": 7, "y": 0.7},
      {"x": 8, "y": 1},
      {"x": 9, "y": 0.4},
      {"x": 10, "y": -0.5}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "window": [{"op": "last_value", "field": "y", "as": "y1"}],
      "frame": [0, 1],
      "sort": [{"field": "x", "order": "ascending"}]
    },
    {"calculate": "datum.y1 - datum.y", "as": "dy"}
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "x"},
        "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "y"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "color": {"value": "red"},
        "x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "x"},
        "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "dy"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {"view": {"width": 400, "height": 300}}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jave, thanks for your help. How does the last value gets calculated dy=0 on x=10? . In my case x is a timestamp, would "sort" work the same? By the way, derivative should be promoted ot its own transform